# Slow query on primary server runs fast on hot standby

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, query-performance

I have a primary PostgreSQL 9.3.4 server with 64GB of RAM that is replicated using streaming replication to a hot standby server with 32GB of RAM. My problem is as follows: I've detected a query that takes a long time to run on my primary server but runs very fast on the standby server. I did an EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT this_.id AS id1_31_0_,
       this_.nom AS nom2_31_0_,
       this_.nom_slug AS nom3_31_0_,
       this_.descripcio AS descripc4_31_0_,
       this_.url AS url5_31_0_,
       this_.data_captura AS data6_31_0_,
       this_.data_publicacio AS data7_31_0_,
       this_.propietari AS propieta8_31_0_,
       this_.privacitat AS privacit9_31_0_,
       this_.desnivellpujada AS desnive10_31_0_,
       this_.desnivellbaixada AS desnive11_31_0_,
       this_.longitud AS longitu13_31_0_,
       this_.beginpoint AS beginpo14_31_0_,
       this_.endpoint AS endpoin15_31_0_,
       this_.caixa3d AS caixa16_31_0_,
       this_.pic_id AS pic17_31_0_,
       this_.skill AS skill18_31_0_,
       this_.spatial_type AS spatial19_31_0_,
       this_.tags_cached AS tags20_31_0_,
       this_.images_cached AS images21_31_0_,
       this_.ncomments AS ncommen22_31_0_,
       this_.group_order AS group23_31_0_,
       this_.author AS author24_31_0_,
       this_.proper_a AS proper25_31_0_,
       this_.duration AS duratio26_31_0_,
       this_.isloop AS isloop27_31_0_,
       this_.seo_country AS seo28_31_0_,
       this_.seo_region AS seo29_31_0_,
       this_.seo_place AS seo30_31_0_,
       this_.source AS source31_31_0_,
       this_.source_name AS source32_31_0_,
       this_.api_key AS api33_31_0_,
       this_.ratingui AS ratingu34_31_0_,
       this_.nratings AS nrating35_31_0_,
       this_.trailrank AS trailra36_31_0_,
       this_.ncoords AS ncoords37_31_0_,
       this_.egeom AS egeom38_31_0_,
       this_.elevels AS elevels39_31_0_,
       this_.elevations AS elevati40_31_0_,
       this_.nphotoswpts AS nphotos41_31_0_,
       this_.nfavourited AS nfavour42_31_0_,
       this_.ncompanions AS ncompan43_31_0_,
       this_.group_id AS group44_31_0_
FROM spatial_artifact this_
WHERE this_.group_id IS NULL
  AND this_.propietari=7649
ORDER BY this_.id DESC LIMIT 20
```

**--PRIMARY SERVER (EXPLAIN ANALYZE output)**

```
"Limit  (cost=0.43..22734.71 rows=20 width=604) (actual time=1804.124..293469.085 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan Backward using "PK_SPATIAL_ARTIFACT" on spatial_artifact this_  (cost=0.43..7776260.84 rows=6841 width=604) (actual time=1804.121..293469.056 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((group_id IS NULL) AND (propietari = 7649))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 2848286"
"Total runtime: 293469.135 ms"
```

**--STANDBY SERVER (EXPLAIN ANALYZE output)**

```
"Limit  (cost=23533.73..23533.78 rows=20 width=604) (actual time=2.566..2.569 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=23533.73..23550.83 rows=6841 width=604) (actual time=2.566..2.567 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: id"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 35kB"
"        ->  Index Scan using idx_own_spas on spatial_artifact this_  (cost=0.43..23351.70 rows=6841 width=604) (actual time=0.037..2.119 rows=618 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (propietari = 7649)"
"Total runtime: 2.612 ms"
```

I've run ANALYZE on my table and have reindexed the index idx_own_spas on my primary server, but it hasn't helped.

Here is the postgresql config of my two servers:

**--PRIMARY SERVER (postgresql.conf)**

```
shared_buffers = 8GB    
work_mem = 42MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 44GB
random_page_cost = 4
seq_page_cost = 1
default_statistics_target = 100
```

**--STANDBY SERVER (postgresql.conf)**

```
shared_buffers = 800MB
work_mem = 20MB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
effective_cache_size = 1024MB
random_page_cost = 4
seq_page_cost = 1
default_statistics_target = 100
```

The EXPLAIN cost estimation seems to be off, but I don't understand why it is happening? Could you shed some light into this? Thank you.

---

**EDIT: Some extra information:**

Table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE spatial_artifact
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  nom character varying(128),
  descripcio character varying(25000),
  data_captura timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  propietari integer NOT NULL,
  privacitat character varying(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'private'::character varying,
  data_publicacio timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  desnivellpujada integer,
  desnivellbaixada integer,
  longitud integer,
  geometria geometry,
  spatial_type smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  tags_cached character varying(1024),
  images_cached text,
  nviews integer DEFAULT 0,
  ndowngpx integer DEFAULT 0,
  nratings smallint DEFAULT 0,
  ndownkml integer DEFAULT 0,
  rating numeric(3,2) DEFAULT 2.50,
  caixa3d box3d NOT NULL,
  bbox geometry NOT NULL,
  group_id integer,
  group_order smallint DEFAULT 0,
  pic_id smallint DEFAULT 0,
  skill smallint DEFAULT 2,
  url character varying(256),
  ncomments smallint DEFAULT 0,
  author character varying(50),
  proper_a character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  beginpoint geometry NOT NULL,
  endpoint geometry,
  trailrank real DEFAULT 0,
  seo_country character varying(3),
  seo_region character varying(15),
  seo_place integer,
  nfavourited integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  togoogle integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  source smallint DEFAULT 0,
  ncoords integer DEFAULT 0,
  egeom character varying,
  elevels character varying,
  duration bigint DEFAULT 0,
  isloop integer DEFAULT 0,
  nom_slug character varying(128),
  source_name character varying(50),
  api_key character varying,
  elevations text,
  ratingui numeric(3,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  wptphotos boolean DEFAULT false,
  ncompanions integer DEFAULT 0,
  nphotoswpts integer DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_SPATIAL_ARTIFACT" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_PICTOGRAM" FOREIGN KEY (pic_id)
      REFERENCES pictogram (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_SPATIAL_ARTIFACT_GROUP" FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
      REFERENCES spatial_artifact (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_SPATIAL_ARTIFACT_USUARI" FOREIGN KEY (propietari)
      REFERENCES usuari (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_bbox CHECK (st_ndims(bbox) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_beginpoint CHECK (st_ndims(beginpoint) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_endpoint CHECK (st_ndims(endpoint) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geometria CHECK (st_ndims(geometria) = 4),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_beginpoint CHECK (st_geometrytype(beginpoint) = 'ST_Point'::text OR beginpoint IS NULL),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_endpoint CHECK (st_geometrytype(endpoint) = 'ST_Point'::text OR endpoint IS NULL),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geometria CHECK (st_geometrytype(geometria) = 'ST_Line'::text OR st_geometrytype(geometria) = 'ST_LineString'::text OR geometria IS NULL),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_bbox CHECK (st_srid(bbox) = 4326),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_beginpoint CHECK (st_srid(beginpoint) = 4326),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_endpoint CHECK (st_srid(endpoint) = 4326),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geometria CHECK (st_srid(geometria) = 4326)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Indexes

```
CREATE INDEX idx_own_spas
  ON spatial_artifact
  USING btree
  (propietari)
  WHERE group_id IS NULL;

CREATE INDEX "FKI_SPATIAL_ARTIFACT_GROUP"
  ON spatial_artifact
  USING btree
  (group_id);


CREATE INDEX idx_seo_spatial_artifact
  ON spatial_artifact
  USING btree
  (seo_country COLLATE pg_catalog."default", seo_region COLLATE pg_catalog."default", seo_place);

CREATE INDEX idx_spatial_artifact_data_publicacio
  ON spatial_artifact
  USING btree
  (data_publicacio)
  WHERE proper_a IS NULL AND privacitat::text = 'public'::text AND (spatial_type = ANY (ARRAY[0, 3]));

CREATE INDEX idx_spatial_artifact_data_publicacio_only
  ON spatial_artifact
  USING btree
  (data_publicacio);

CREATE INDEX idx_spatial_artifact_propietari
  ON spatial_artifact
  USING btree
  (propietari);
```

**Size of the affected table:**

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('spatial_artifact'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 98 GB
(1 row)


select relpages,reltuples, relname from pg_class where relname in ('idx_own_spas ','spatial_artifact','PK_SPATIAL_ARTIFACT');

 relpages |  reltuples  |       relname       
----------+-------------+---------------------
    49217 | 9.70814e+06 | PK_SPATIAL_ARTIFACT
    14329 | 5.22472e+06 | idx_own_spas
  3423824 | 1.11087e+07 | spatial_artifact
(3 rows)
```

**Hardware**
As far as the hardware is concerned, the primary server's CPU, RAM and disks are all better than the standby server. For instance, the primary server's db is persisted on a SSD, while the standby server runs on magnetic disks.

**System stats**

Nothing out of ordinary as far as I can tell:

top (by cpu)

```
top - 15:26:05 up 667 days,  4:36,  1 user,  load average: 1.86, 2.24, 2.25
Tasks: 158 total,   2 running, 156 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 13.6 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.6 id,  1.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  66082816 total, 64774132 used,  1308684 free,   322604 buffers
KiB Swap: 33554428 total,     3664 used, 33550764 free, 16937780 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
17356 root      20   0 19.5g  15g 2.3g S   108 25.3   4837:05 java
 4540 postgres  20   0 8481m 264m 250m R    13  0.4   0:02.24 postgres
 5592 postgres  20   0 8480m 185m 172m S     6  0.3   0:01.37 postgres
 6787 root      20   0 24568 1440 1060 R     6  0.0   0:00.01 top
31897 root      20   0 36632 4528  976 S     6  0.0 215:24.83 nginx
    1 root      20   0 10648   32    0 S     0  0.0   5:51.09 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:01.40 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0  26:29.26 ksoftirqd/0
    6 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   2:37.09 migration/0
    7 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   2:16.42 watchdog/0
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   3:00.24 migration/1
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   6:29.60 ksoftirqd/1
   12 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:51.26 watchdog/1
   13 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:31.24 migration/2
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   5:37.32 ksoftirqd/2
   16 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:34.45 watchdog/2
   17 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:34.16 migration/3
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   4:38.17 ksoftirqd/3
   20 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:28.69 watchdog/3
   21 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:29.48 migration/4
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   4:07.97 ksoftirqd/4
   24 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:29.92 watchdog/4
   25 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   1:24.09 migration/5
```

top (by memory)

```
top - 15:27:43 up 667 days,  4:37,  1 user,  load average: 1.51, 2.01, 2.17
Tasks: 156 total,   1 running, 155 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 13.6 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.6 id,  1.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  66082816 total, 65083212 used,   999604 free,   331972 buffers
KiB Swap: 33554428 total,     3664 used, 33550764 free, 17188544 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
30270 root      20   0 28.4g  26g  932 S     0 42.7   2042:56 redis-server
17356 root      20   0 20.7g  15g 2.3g S   137 25.3   4839:24 java
 8911 postgres  20   0 8436m 8.1g 8.1g S     0 12.9  18:49.76 postgres
30259 root      20   0 4058m 3.7g 1012 S     7  5.9   1981:01 redis-server
 8912 postgres  20   0 8433m 1.8g 1.7g S     0  2.8  18:19.52 postgres
32263 postgres  20   0 8482m 550m 536m S     0  0.9   0:05.71 postgres
 4540 postgres  20   0 8482m 456m 441m S     0  0.7   0:04.16 postgres
 5592 postgres  20   0 8482m 312m 298m S     0  0.5   0:02.56 postgres
 5593 postgres  20   0 8477m 305m 291m S     0  0.5   0:02.35 postgres
 2810 postgres  20   0 8477m 296m 283m S     0  0.5   0:02.50 postgres
 5591 postgres  20   0 8477m 230m 216m S     0  0.4   0:01.48 postgres
 8908 postgres  20   0 8429m 216m 215m S     0  0.3   3:13.31 postgres
 4556 postgres  20   0 8477m 191m 178m S     0  0.3   0:01.16 postgres
 5624 postgres  20   0 8480m 182m 169m S     7  0.3   0:00.74 postgres
 5632 postgres  20   0 8476m  46m  37m S     0  0.1   0:00.11 postgres
17472 root      20   0  391m  42m 5868 S     0  0.1   1:56.15 java
 5631 postgres  20   0 8457m  20m  16m S     0  0.0   0:00.03 postgres
 8913 postgres  20   0 8433m  17m  16m S     0  0.0  21:01.87 postgres
15261 root      20   0 54496 9560 1792 S     0  0.0   5:45.10 munin-node
 2338 root      20   0  117m 5420  436 S     0  0.0 238:08.17 rsyslogd
31897 root      20   0 36632 4528  976 S     0  0.0 215:25.31 nginx
28132 root      20   0 71372 3736 2844 S     0  0.0   0:00.02 sshd
31896 root      20   0 35628 3472  980 S     0  0.0 212:50.13 nginx
28512 xorxio1   20   0 21964 3340 1684 S     0  0.0   0:00.04 bash
31898 root      20   0 35404 3336  976 S     7  0.0 221:58.88 nginx
 8176 root      20   0 35024 3328 1700 S     0  0.0   0:00.03 nginx
31899 root      20   0 35404 3304  976 S     0  0.0 213:28.28 nginx
31900 root      20   0 35388 3304  976 S     0  0.0 210:39.00 nginx
30446 postfix   20   0 42624 3160 2004 S     0  0.0   0:05.03 tlsmgr
31903 root      20   0 35140 3048  968 S     0  0.0 247:17.16 nginx
31901 root      20   0 35172 3040  976 S     0  0.0 210:03.54 nginx
31902 root      20   0 35100 3040  976 S     0  0.0 261:43.64 nginx
19032 postgres  20   0 8434m 2836 1568 S     0  0.0   0:44.81 postgres
29894 postfix   20   0 40356 2788 1808 S     0  0.0  12:14.27 qmgr
 8914 postgres  20   0 8434m 2420 1364 S     0  0.0   1:11.83 postgres
 8909 postgres  20   0 20492 2400  760 S     0  0.0   0:42.46 postgres
```

vmstat 1

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 3  0   3664 1115260 308108 16988420    0    0   139   424    0    0 14  1 85  1
13  0   3664 1109744 308156 16988740    0    0  2036  3536 5340 4782 17  1 79  3
 1  0   3664 1113616 308168 16989100    0    0  3540   296 4986 4691 14  0 84  2
 2  0   3664 1107704 308608 16992984    0    0  2100   220 6467 5861 14  1 84  2
 2  0   3664 1105884 308652 16994704    0    0  1804   728 5163 4835 15  1 82  2
 2  0   3664 1103364 308652 16997228    0    0  2288    40 4597 4601  9  1 89  1
 1  0   3664 1094156 308800 17006684    0    0  1808   236 9617 8739 18  1 79  2
 1  0   3664 1090656 308840 17008044    0    0  2196   284 7062 5923 26  1 72  1
 0  0   3664 1089352 308852 17009588    0    0  1048   276 4306 3951  9  1 89  1
 3  0   3664 1087740 308852 17011224    0    0  1600     0 4533 4066  6  1 92  1
```

sar -dp 1

```
03:16:09 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
03:16:10 PM       sdb    124.00   2432.00     32.00     19.87      0.02      0.13      0.13      1.60
03:16:11 PM       sdb    150.00   3312.00    160.00     23.15      0.02      0.11      0.11      1.60
03:16:12 PM       sdb    144.00   3296.00    368.00     25.44      0.05      0.36      0.28      4.00
03:16:13 PM       sdb    124.00   3104.00     32.00     25.29      0.03      0.26      0.23      2.80
03:16:14 PM       sdb    139.00   3312.00     16.00     23.94      0.04      0.29      0.26      3.60
03:16:15 PM       sdb     90.00   1472.00    120.00     17.69      0.02      0.18      0.18      1.60
03:16:16 PM       sdb    145.00   3616.00    128.00     25.82      0.04      0.28      0.28      4.00
```

sar -q 1 (CPU is an Intel Xeon E5 with 6 physical cores)

```
03:18:29 PM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked
03:18:30 PM         2       657      2.96      2.56      2.26         0
03:18:31 PM         1       657      2.96      2.56      2.26         0
03:18:32 PM         1       657      2.96      2.56      2.26         0
03:18:33 PM         1       657      2.96      2.56      2.26         0
03:18:34 PM         2       657      2.72      2.52      2.25         0
03:18:35 PM         3       657      2.72      2.52      2.25         0
03:18:36 PM         1       657      2.72      2.52      2.25         1
03:18:37 PM         1       657      2.72      2.52      2.25         0
03:18:38 PM         2       657      2.72      2.52      2.25         0
```

sar -w 1

```
03:20:47 PM    proc/s   cswch/s
03:20:48 PM      0.00   4902.00
03:20:49 PM     15.00   5289.00
03:20:50 PM      0.00   4663.00
03:20:51 PM      2.00   5223.00
03:20:52 PM      1.00   5124.00
03:20:53 PM      0.00   4426.00
03:20:54 PM      0.00   4327.00
03:20:55 PM      1.00   3936.00
03:20:56 PM      0.00   4369.00
03:20:57 PM     28.00   6492.00
03:20:58 PM      1.00   4465.00
03:20:59 PM      0.00   4028.00
```

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. Your primary doesn't appear to be under great stress. Can you swap your Primary postgresql.conf out for your mirror's one and see if that helps? I know your server has been up for more than a year and you probably don't want to be rebooting it every time you want to change a parameter. And you also have to consider your entire workload. However, I know from Oracle that it's possible to set the shared pool to too large a value causing response times to increase. Maybe some analagous phenomenon is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad plan is probably a culmination of many problems.  Which means that there are many ways of tackling it.  My guess is that the culmination of problems causes two plans to look falsely close to each other in cost, and then the differences in memory setting (probably `effective_cache_size`) between master and slave is the straw that broke the camel's back and tips the master over to using the wrong one.

The simplest starting point for tackling it may be this one:

```
"        ->  Index Scan using idx_own_spas on spatial_artifact this_  (cost=0.43..23351.70 rows=6841 width=604) (actual time=0.037..2.119 rows=618 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (propietari = 7649)"
```

This is simple because the scan runs to completion, and only has a single index qualification, and yet the estimate is off by a factor of 10.  Since your statistic are up to date, the problem must be an inadequate default_statistics_target.  You can increase that globally, or increase it just for the column `propietari` using [SET STATISTICS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html), and then re-analyzing the table. If this estimation problem were fixed, the master would almost certainly switch to that faster plan as it would appear even faster yet.

Another problem is that it thinks rows meeting the criteria `((group_id IS NULL) AND (propietari = 7649))` are distributed randomly over the values of `this_.id`, which they apparently are not.  That causes it to think the LIMIT clause will kick in much sooner than it actually does, so making the slow plan look like it will be faster than it will be.  Unfortunately, there is nothing simple you can do to make this estimation better.  But, if you create the right index, you could provide a third plan which actually is much faster, and also looks much faster, than either of the two current ones.

That index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_own_spas
  ON spatial_artifact
  USING btree
  (propietari,id)
  WHERE group_id IS NULL;
```

You can replace the existing similar index but without the `id` column with this index, so it should not take up much additional space or maintenance overhead.

Finally, you can change `effective_cache_size` within each session, so it would be easy to change this value on the master and on the slave to see if that is truly which is tipping the plan over from the good plan to the bad plan.  But if that is the case, that still doesn't tell you what to do about it.  Just because a certain value causes a bad planner choice for one query doesn't mean it is not set properly for the system as a whole.  So hopefully one of the early two methods will work.

Comment: The solution that worked in the end was creating the modified index. I tried changing the statistics setting, but that didn't produce any results. Setting enable_seqscan to false didn't force the query planner to use the alternative plan either.